# DataforSEO API - Google Maps API - response in nested dictionary not JSON?

Tags: python, json, dictionary, response

Due to example codes and technical help, API response of the post request to Google Maps SERP API

```json
[

    {
    "language_name": "English",
    "location_name": "London,England,United Kingdom",
    "keyword": "shops",
    "device": "desktop",
    "os": "windows"
    }

]
```

should give me nice formatted JSON. Unfortunately, I am receiving a nested dictionary, which is not accepted by JSON viewers. I can work with it changing <kbd>'</kbd> to <kbd>"</kbd>, then changing <kbd>"</kbd> inside the texts into <kbd>'</kbd>, replace `None` with `NULL`, etc etc, etc. and then work with it as a JSON. But I don't believe it is something that you, my dear, experience Developers do. Where is my mistake? I am a beginner and it is my first cry for help, as I don't understand why I am stuck at this point.

Comment: What are you using to view json? Valid json can be a nested dictionary, so it's more how you step into it to access the values.  Can we a see a sample of the nested dictionary response? That will help us help you.

Comment: Thank you for your message! I have just received the answer from Technical Support Team. And the answer was as easy as that: "When I am using Microsoft Visual Studio and get the results in the command line - I also get the result with single quotes and their format is similar to your. However, it's easy to resolve if you save the results into a file, for example. If you save them into a file or get in any other way that uses another encoding - you will get the JSON." And it worked. As simple as that. So much to learn..

Answer (score 1):

Dataforseo API return response in Json format, here you can check [Dataforsoe maps live api](https://docs.dataforseo.com/v3/serp/google/maps/live/advanced/?python)

If it does not work, you can just dumps it through the Python JSON library:

```
import json
json_response = json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False)
```